# iOS 11 updating Location Services from "While Using" to "Always"

Tags: ios, swift, location, cllocationmanager

I'm recently working in an app update to add location services in background.

The app currently supports "While using the App" location service and I want to make support "Always allow".

I'm keeping in mind that this feature should cover two scenarios.

1. New users, that haven't downloaded the app.
2. Current users, that already have granted the app permission to receive the device's location while using the app.

Scenario 1 is working perfectly, but for scenario 2 something weird is happening.

When I launch the app, right after the splash screen, iOS prompts the user to escalate the app's authorization level with two options, "Only while using the app" and "Always Allow".

I want to escalate this later, not right after the splash screen.

Does someone know why this happening?

Comment: When are you initializing the location manager / requesting authorization? It seems likely that you can't actually control when this updated authorization alert appears, but it's possible that it's triggered when you first try to use location services after re-launching the app.

Comment: In a specific View Controller all Location's are handled. There is where I handle to escalate auth level. But this alert appears and this VC it's not even instantiated.

Comment: [The documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/choosing_the_authorization_level_for_location_services/requesting_always_authorization) doesn't seem to say that this alert is supposed to show up immediately (rather seems like it would only show when you request the new authorization). So I would first make absolutely sure you're not requesting authorization or anything at launch / earlier than you expect.

Comment: That's has been my approach for the last 3 days. I'm getting out of options. =/

Comment: Hi @shim , after deep debugging I found what's going on. One of my dependencies was checking for Background Mode available and for Location Key inside app plist file. It was really hard to find that because Xcode search doesn't find anything inside project's frameworks. Even if the framework code it's present. I found that with a symbolic breakpoint over entire CoreLocation lib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was solved with a symbolic breakpoint over all CoreLocation lib.

How?

1 - put a breakpoint on the first line of didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

2 - start your app

3 - on console panel, insert this command to break in every method of CoreLocation lib

```
lldb: break set -r CoreLocation
```

4 - resume your app

Now the debug will stop at every function invoked from CoreLocation lib

The problem was that a dependency was checking for background modes without my realizing it, so this was triggering the alert.